# How to pass Git credentials in a Kustomize build command?

Tags: kubernetes, kustomize

I have a *kustomization.yaml* file that uses a private repository as a resource:

```
apiVersion: kustomize.config.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Kustomization
resources:
  - https://gitlab.com/my-user/k8s-base-cfg.git
patchesStrategicMerge:
  - app-patch.yaml
```

I want to automate this on a Jenkins Pipeline. I don't know how to pass Git credentials to the kustomize build command. Is there any option to do that?

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't, you would set up the credentials in git before starting Kustomize. In this case probably something very simple like `git config --global user.password "your password"` but look up the `credentials.helper` setting for more complex options, either from a local file or a tool that reads from some backing store directly.

Answer (score 1):

@coderanger's answer is correct, but doesn't work for me. I use this:

```
git config --global credential.helper store
echo "https://$GITUSER:$PASSWORD@github.com" >> "${HOME}/.git-credentials"
```

If you're using GitHub, `$GITUSER` = `git` (it's ignored) and `$PASSWORD` = a personal access token.